# How to reset style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have following styles :

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,10,0" />   
</Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.TextBoxStyleKey}}" TargetType="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4" />
   <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />-->
</Style>
<Style TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />                               
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />          
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>           
 </Style>
<Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.TextBoxStyleKey}}" >
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />            
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="CalendarItem">
   <Setter Property="Style" Value="{x:Null}"/>             
</Style>
```

Now the textblock style is messing up the calendar, when displayed, the dates and month names are all big and partially visible.

I tried to reset the Calendar style by using :

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarItem">
   <Setter Property="Style" Value="{x:Null}"/>             
</Style>
```

but it seems to have no effcet on the calendar. I also tried targettype="Calendar", but no impact.

How do I reset the calendar style to default?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your textblock style a key:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="tbCustomStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,10,0" />   
</Style>
```

That way the textblock default style wont be affected for the calendar.

Then when you want to apply this particular style in your xaml, you can use the following:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource tbCustomStyle}">

</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Agreed. This is the clean way to do things. But in this particular case, I am looking to <b>reset<b>TextBlock style for Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare an empty style for this type:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:Calendar}" x:Key="CalendarItem">
</Style>
```

Let me know if this resets the style.